# JQuery overlay close

Tags: jquery, overlay

hi I have got the following code and I want to close this overlay popup once the save has been completed. HTML section displays the html code block I have and Javascript block explains how I'm trying to call this overlay.

```
<javascript>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var triggers = $(".modalInput").overlay({
        closeOnClick: false
    });


var weightedTemplateButtons = $("#addWeightsPopup button").click(function(e) {

        var save = weightedTemplateButtons.index(this) === 0;

        if (save) {
            if (validateWeightedTemplate()) {
                completeWeightedTemplate();
                addNewWeightedTemplate();

                                   /*this doesn't work*/
                weightedTemplateButtons.overlay().close();

            }
        }

        return e.preventDefault();
    });

</javascript>

<html>

<button id="addButton" rel="#addWeightsPopup" onclick="addButton_onClick();" class="modalInput StdButton">Add</button>


<div id="addWeightsPopup" class="modal addWeights">
  <span>Sample Text</span>
    <div class="addWeightsButton">
       <button class="StdButton stdButton" type="submit"  id="weightedTemplateAddButton">Save</button>
       <button class="close StdButton stdButton">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you consider using jqueryui, as this will handle a lot of this stuff for you.

Comment: overlay is a really nice plugin, jquery is heavy and does not cover this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found the answer....

triggers.eq(0).overlay().close()

0 - index of the button

So if you have two buttons, then
triggers.eq(1).overlay().close()

Comment: or other option would be to use this $('#addButton').overlay().close()

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the popup with ID of that div like

```
$("#addWeightsPopup").hide();
```